# Column to be parsed Dynamically in PySpark

Tags: parsing, dynamic, pyspark, schema

Column names and No of columns in each new data came are different . I want to columns to be parsed dynamically in PySpark and creating unique schema for incoming datasets.

```
Input 1 : old 
        Name    Position_-07/05/2020  Department
        Peter     Grade-A             LS
        Robin     Grade-B             LS
        Rosy      Grade-A             HS
        Silver    Grade-C             HS
        Jeo       Grade-B             AS


Input 2: df_new
       Name    Position_-07/06/2020  Department   percentage
        Peter     Grade-A             LS            90
        Robin     Grade-A             LS            85
        Rosy      Grade-A             HS            92
        Silver    Grade-C             HS            60
        Jeo       Grade-B             AS            75
        Wilson    Grade-A             HR            93


old_column=["name",Position_07/05/2020,Department]
col_new=[]
col_current=df_new.columns
for filed_name in df_new.columns:
       if filed_name in  old_columns:
              col_new.append(field_name)
new_col=set(col_new+col_current)
schema= [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in new_col]
```

I am stuck in after that . I want unique schema for two datasests.

```
 out put: Name  Position_07/05/2020 position_07/06/2020 Department percentage
          Peter   Grade-A             Grade-A             LS          90
          Robin   Grade-B             Grade-A             LS          85
          Rosy    Grade-A             Grade-A             HS          92
          Silver  Grade-C             Grade-c             HS          60
          Jeo     Grade-B             Grade-B             AS          75
          Wilson   NULL               Grade-A             HR           93
```

Comment: can you show, based on the input what would be the expected output ?

Comment: I have Added sample output

Comment: what happens if there are 2 Peter ? What will be the next file schema ? Just a new date for position ?

Comment: There is No primary key function on dataset . Just simply add a new record to dataframe remaining values has null . I want looking Dynamic schema No of columns and name are different . every month i will get some extra columns  of a file . so we decide unique schema with "N"  fields.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, that's just a basic join.

```py
old.join(df_new, on="Name")
```